# How to convert 1 as true and 0 as false in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a javascript program, i need to  convert 1 as true and 0 as false;
My program snippets is like following

```
var has_extra_status = 1;
$("#MealOptionFoodHasExtras").attr('checked', has_extra_status);
```

I have a status variable which hold numeric value 0 or 1;
Based  on that one checkbox will be checked or not.
How can i achieve that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$("#MealOptionFoodHasExtras").prop('checked', has_extra_status);` will work

Answer (score 2):

You can use .prop() inbuild function instead of .attr() because jQuery .attr() deprecated/removed for use with "checked" and "disabled" properties . [Reference](https://www.drupal.org/node/2417463)

```
var val="";
if(has_extra_status==1)
{
val= true;
} 
else if(has_extra_status==0)
{
val= false;
}

 $("#MealOptionFoodHasExtras").prop('checked', val);
```

Comment: Why? `.prop()` handles `0` as `false` and `>0` as `true`. No need for any boolean conversions. Additionaly `if` also handles numbers as boolean... `if(has_extra_status)`

Answer (score 0):

`checked` is a *property* and should be modified with a *property* setter [**`.prop(property, value)`**](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop2) instead of `.attr()`.
It laso reads numeric values (among others) as boolean.

```
// for true:
var has_extra_status = 1;
// var has_extra_status = 999;
// var has_extra_status = 'yes!';
// var has_extra_status = true;

// for false:
// var has_extra_status = 0;
// var has_extra_status = '';
// var has_extra_status = false;
// var has_extra_status = null;

$("#MealOptionFoodHasExtras").prop('checked', has_extra_status);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a if condition and assign a Boolean

```
var status;
if(has_extra_status==1)
{
status = true;
} 
else if(has_extra_status==0)
{
status = false;
}
```

then

```
$("#MealOptionFoodHasExtras").attr('checked',status);
```